# Array not appending

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I am trying to import data from a file and then add it to an array. I know that this is not the *best* way to add elements to a numpy array. Nevertheless, why is the data not appending? The last element of the csv is 1.1 and thats what i get when i do print(dd)

```
with open('C:\\Users\jez40\.PyCharmCE2018.2\8_Data.csv', 'r') as data_file:
data = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')
for i in data:
    t = []
    d = []
    dd = []
    t.append([float(i[0])])
    d.append([float(i[1])])
    dd.append([float(i[2])])
    t = np.array(t)
    d = np.array(d)
    dd = np.array(dd)
print (dd)
```

Comment: Because every iteration of the loop you are re-assigning `t`, `d` and `dd` to empty lists `[]`

Comment: Put your `t = [],  d = [], dd = []` before the for loop and `t = np.array(t) d = np.array(d)  dd = np.array(dd)` after the for loop

Comment: thank you i completely overlooked that

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem lies in the fact that every iteration of your loop you are re-assigning `t`, `d` and `dd` to empty lists `[]`. If your end-all goal is to acquire `numpy` arrays for these variables, I would recommend using `pd.read_csv()` to convert your csv file to a dataframe. Take this sample csv:

```
t,d,dd
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Using `pd.read_csv()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\jez40\.PyCharmCE2018.2\8_Data.csv')
```

Gives:

```
   t  d  dd
0  1  2   3
1  4  5   6
2  7  8   9
```

Then you can query your columns to return them as `pd.Series()`:

```
t = df['t']
d = df['d']
dd = df['dd']
```

Or you can convert them to `np.array()`:

```
t = np.array(df['t'])
d = np.array(df['d'])
dd = np.array(df['dd'])
```